# Xamarin UWP project doesn't install dependencies from Nuget

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, xamarin.uwp

I have a case that when I install any nuget package on my xamarin forms project, only UWP project doesnt install correctly. It installs only the main package but dependencies arent installed. This seems not occuring for Android and IOS projects but only UWP. as you can see below. I have this package installed and has dependencies

[image]

But when I check one of the dependency in the list, it shows that not installed.

[image]

however output window indicates that it is installed and written into project.lock.json file and it is there i can find it.

[image]

But I am using project.json file as shown below.

[image]

when I check the project.json file, it has only reference for main package which is Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. there is no reference for dependencies.

So my questions are; what are the difference between project.json and project.lock.json? Do I need both of them? this project is created 2 years ago using Vs2015 and always upgraded. If I create a new project using Vs2017 15.5.3 version,  i dont see neither of these files under UWP project?
what is the problem here? can somebody shed some lights on this issue?

EDIT:
based answer below, I should assume that dependencies are installed if I install the main package but for example, I installed this Akavache nuget as shown below

[image]

It popups that it will install dependencies like akavache.core for example but one installation is finished on nuget-solution, i am seeing the screen below. How can I ensure that it is already installed?

One other thing that I see csproj extension near my uwp project. I am not sure if that it something to do with changing form Project.json file to csproj as nuget imports location.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are the difference between project.json and project.lock.json? Do I need both of them? this project is created 2 years ago using Vs2015 and always upgraded. If I create a new project using Vs2017 15.5.3 version, i dont see neither of these files under UWP project?

According to [`project.json reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/project-json#projectlockjson) documentation, the `project.json` file maintains a list of packages used in a project, known as a package reference format. It supersedes packages.config but is in turn **superseded** by PackageReference with NuGet 4.0+.

The `project.lock.json` file is generated in the process of restoring the NuGet packages in projects that use project.json.

> But when I check one of the dependency in the list, it shows that not installed.

Actually, the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` version 6.0.6 contains [`.NET native compilers`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/6.0.5). You have no need to install `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler` individually.

And the latest `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler` is only available in `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0;build 16299)`. if it has been installed individually, you need to modify your target min version to 16299.

**Update**

> It popups that it will install dependencies like akavache.core for example but one installation is finished on nuget-solution, i am seeing the screen below. How can I ensure that it is already installed?

`Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler` will not display in the project References folder, it will be management with package manager tool.

[image]

And you could find `project.assets.json` in the following folder. it has recorded the nuget package you have installed.

```
Path: C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\GetPlainTextTest\GetPlainTextTest\obj\project.assets.json
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing all these confusion for me. But Is it not a big disadvantage using Fall Creators Update as min because not everybody has this update and I will be missing so many potential users

Comment: You could also continue to use [`Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/5.3.2) previous version, and it also contain [`Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler/).

Comment: I have extended my question because your answer is not clear for me. especially regarding 2nd point. please see the edit part. I appreciate if you can clarify. thanks